# Is there any double staining method to visualise separate colour for plant tissue and fungal tissue?

Tags: microbiology, plant-anatomy, mycology, staining

Is there any **double staining** method for developing separate colour on fungal tissue and plant tissue when the said 2 types of tissues are intermingled?

Unlike my [previous question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/85728/how-can-i-stain-only-the-chitin-but-not-cellulose-or-glucans), this question not necessarily need  to target specifically chitin and/or N-acetylglucosamine but looks for any principle to differentially stain intermingled plant tissue and fungal tissue.